# Total probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I saw this exercise on this side and I tried to understand the solution but it looks like the solution given has a mistake or I am doing it wrong.
So I decided to seek for help.

Two reinforced concrete buildings A and B are located in a seismic region. It is estimated that an impending earthquake in the region might be strong (S), moderate (M), or weak (W) with probabilities.

P (S) = 0.02, P (M) = 0.2, and P (W) = 0.78.

The probabilities of failure of each building if these earthquakes occur are 0.20, 0.05, and 0.01, respectively.Due to similar procedures used in the design and construction of the two buildings, it is estimated that if building A fails the probability that building B will also fail is 0.50, 0.15, and 0.02 for the three types of earthquakes. If building A has failed and building B has survived, what is the probability that the earthquake was not strong?

I solved this exercise in a different way but I am not sure if it is right. I got a result of 0.383

We need to find $P(\neg S|(\neg A\cap B))=\frac{P(\neg S)P((\neg A\cap B)|\neg S)}{P(\neg A\cap B)}=\frac{P(W \cup M)*P(\neg A\cap B)|(W \cup M)}{P(\neg A\cap B)}=\frac{0.98*0.0534}{0.087}=0.383$

I found $P(\neg A\cap B)$ using formula for total probability.

Where $\neg A\cap B$  means A fails and B survives.

Can anyone tell me if I did it the right way.

Comment: In your notation, is the interpretation of the numbers $0.5$, $0.15$, and $0.02$ supposed to be $P\bigl(\neg B \mid (\neg A) \cap S\bigr)$, $P\bigl(\neg B \mid (\neg A) \cap M\bigr)$, and $P\bigl(\neg B \mid (\neg A) \cap W\bigr)$, respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > The probabilities of failure of each building if these earthquakes occur are 0.20, 0.05, and 0.01, respectively.

Those should be the probability of each building failing under condition of each type.

$\qquad{\mathsf P(\lnot A\mid S)=0.20\\\mathsf P(\lnot A\mid M)=0.05\\\mathsf P(\lnot A\mid W)=0.01}$

So $~\mathsf P(S\mid\lnot A)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(S)\,\mathsf P(\lnot A\mid S)}{\mathsf P(S)\,\mathsf P(\lnot A\mid S)+\mathsf P(M)\,\mathsf P(\lnot A\mid M)+\mathsf P(W)\,\mathsf P(\lnot A\mid W)}$ etcetera.

> > it is estimated that if building A fails the probability that building B will also fail is 0.50, 0.15, and 0.02 for the three types of earthquakes.

As shoteyes commented; you are given the probabilities for $B$ failing under condition each of the three types *and* of $A$ failing.

$\quad{\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid \lnot A\cap S)=0.50\\\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid\lnot A\cap M)=0.15\\\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid \lnot A\cap W)=0.02}$

> > If building A has failed and building B has survived, what is the probability that the earthquake was not strong?

$$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(\lnot S\mid\lnot A\cap\lnot B)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P((M\cup W)\cap \lnot B\mid\lnot A)}{\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid\lnot A)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(M\mid\lnot A)\,\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid\lnot A\cap M)+\mathsf P(W\mid\lnot A)\,\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid\lnot A\cap W)}{\mathsf P(S\mid\lnot A)\,\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid\lnot A\cap S)+\mathsf P(M\mid\lnot A)\,\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid\lnot A\cap M)+\mathsf P(W\mid\lnot A)\,\mathsf P(\lnot B\mid\lnot A\cap W)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{0.15\,\mathsf P(M\mid\lnot A)+0.02\,\mathsf P(W\mid\lnot A)}{0.50\,\mathsf P(S\mid\lnot A)+0.15\,\mathsf P(M\mid\lnot A)+0.02\,\mathsf P(W\mid\lnot A)}\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: I think the desired quantity is $P\bigl(\neg S \mathrel{\bigm\vert} (\neg A) \cap B\bigr)$ instead of $P\bigl(\neg S \mathrel{\bigm\vert} (\neg A) \cap (\neg B)\bigr)$.